# What is the most efficient way to extract certain parts of a string?

Tags: c#

I have the following object:

```
public class Color
{
   public string RGB = "000225123";

}
```

I need to be able to parse out the R,G, and B components, but they may not be in that exact, however, I will know the order.  So one way, it might be `RGB`, but another way it might be `RBG`.

I thought about something like this:

```
string G =  RGB.Substring(RGB.IndexOf('2'),3);
```

but here I happen to know where the G starts and ends, so I can hard-code it, which leads me to another question of what is the best way to store the order. I have thought about doing something like:

```
string order = "RGB";

string RGB = "000225123";

string R = RGB.Substring(order.IndexOf('R'),3);
```

The above works, but what about the scenario where each part can be a varied length, so `R` can be 2 or 3 characters for example, would that be something I store separately or would I store it within the order?

I might have a number like this:

`28-34-29-000-00.0`

or it could be in the order

`29-34-28-000-00.0`

In the above the `28` and `29` are switched and I will know this order, I will just need to know how to parse it out.

Here is a more realistic scenario and solution, but I am not sure if it is efficient enough:

string order = "TSR";

```
string value = "20-10-28-0000-0011";

string[] tokens = value .Split('-');

string t= tokens[order.IndexOf('T')];

string s= tokens[order.IndexOf('S')];

string r= tokens[order.IndexOf('R')];
```

Comment: Why are you using strings instead of structures?

Comment: "What about the scenario where each part can be a varied length" - this is a stupid idea, don't do it in the first place.

Comment: @millimoose - No reason, I just happen to put that in this example.  What benefit do structures bring me in this case?

Comment: How many variations will there be? Are there two or three possible formats, or do you need to descibe any possible format, like RRRGGBBB, BBGGGGRRR, GGRBBB, BRRRG, RGGGGGBBB, RRGB, GGGBBBBR, BGR, BBBGR, RBBBGGG, RGGGGB, et.c.?

Comment: Isn't possible for you to store R, G and B sepparately (class, structure or three variables)? That way your code is way more clear and your substring problem dissapears.

Comment: @Xaisoft You avoid wasting time on trying to find the "best" solution to solve a nonproblem. A color is three integers. Use three integers to store it.

Comment: @millimoose - I am using RGB as an example here, in reality, there is data that is varied in length.

Comment: Do you control the input data? If you do, you can make them all zero padded to 3 characters or make them zero padded hexadecimal numbers which would make only two characters per color channel.

Comment: @Xaisoft Ah. The point kind of remains. If you need to store data as strings (to save it into a file for example), you should prefer having the delimiters explicit *if at all possible*. XML or JSON serialisation works well.

Comment: @Guffa - There are multiple formats.

Comment: You should first set the rule of how the value will be populated? R, G and B would always be of 3 characters or 4 characters. This will help in implementing the efficient solution. If enough characters are not available then you may use leading zeros to complete the length.

Comment: You should also avoid having multiple formats to store the same type of data. If this is not possible, make it explicit in the string data which format is in use, then hardcode parsing it.

Comment: That said, this seems like an [X-Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what you ultimately hope to accomplish. Don't ask about a possibly harebrained idea of solving a problem you don't explain.

Comment: Instead of storing the format as a string, store it as either a reference to the parser (as in my solution) OR store an identifier which can be used by the factory as IColorParser GetParser(IOrderIdentifier identifier);  Then use a dictionary to store the parsers as IDictionary<IOrderIdentifier, IColorParser> _parserDictionary;

Comment: What is efficient enough?  if there is no performance issue in that area of the code, then it is efficient enough.  What are you using to define efficiency?

Comment: I guess it is efficient,  I am parsing them out and then using each part to pass to a stored proc that will search a database.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an interface which contains a method to parse.

Eg,

```
IParseColorString
{
  ColorParts Parse(String s);
}

ColorParts
{
  public string R {get;}
  public string G {get;}
  public String B {get;}
  // or if you wanted the int directly have int return type instead of string
}
```

Then have all the classes with the appropriate ordering derive the interface:

```
ParseRGB : IParseColorString
{
    public ColorParts Parse(String s)
    {
       //  parsing logic for RGB
    }
}

ParseRBG : IParseColorString
{
  public ColorParts Parse(String s)
  {
     // parsing logic for RBG
  }
}
```

Then use them as you like.  You can even have a factory which has them as static instances

```
ColorParsingFactory
{
    public static IParseColorString ParseRGB {get{/* gets the RGB parser */}}
    public static IParseColorString ParseRBG {get{/* gets the RBG parser */}}
}
```

Comment: Is this too much overhead though?

Comment: I do not believe it is too much code.  It is very clean and gives a single place for converting the string to what you want based on one specific format.  If you have a lot of formats you are parsing, you can probably create a more generic parser which takes an expression perhaps so that you can arbitrarily generate any parser logic you want and still pass the parser around.

Comment: +1. @Xaisoft, you've asked for "fastest" solution - so you don't want to waste time on parsing multiple formats and have only minimal code necessary to parse current format.

Comment: I updated my post, let me know if that is sufficient if I have always  have a delimiting character?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this to extract a component from a string:

```
public static int GetComponent(string data, string format, char component) {
  return Int32.Parse(new String(data.Where((c, i) => format[i] == component).ToArray()));
}
```

Usage:

```
string color = "000225123";
string format = "RRRGGGBBB";

int red = GetComponent(color, format, 'R');
int green = GetComponent(color, format, 'G');
int blue = GetComponent(color, format, 'B');
```

It would work for any format that you can describe that way:

```
string time = "2012-10-12 19:02";
string format = "YYYY MM DD hh mm";

int year = GetComponent(time, format, 'Y');
int month = GetComponent(time, format, 'M');
int day = GetComponent(time, format, 'D');
int hour = GetComponent(time, format, 'h');
int minute = GetComponent(time, format, 'm');
```

Comment: How would this change if I had something like `RR-GGG-BBB`, a delimitting character to separate out each part.

Comment: @Xaisoft: That's a completely different kind of format. For that you would rather use `color.Split('-')` to get an array, and then parse the items.

Comment: Right, my input will be delimited by the "-" character

Comment: @Xaisoft: If each number has a fixed length, you can use the function described above. If not, then it's not the kind of format that you describe in the original function, and you would base the parsing on the delimiter only.

Comment: I will update my post with a more realistic scenario and solution.

Comment: @Xaisoft: That solution is certainly efficient enough. It even scales fairly well, so it won't give you any nasty performance issues as long as the strings aren't extremely long.

Comment: In your LINQ query, where is c coming from?  Can you explain what it is doing?

Comment: @Xaisoft: The parameter `c` is the character in the data string. It's not used in the lambda expression, as it's irrelevant to whether the character should be included or not, as it's only the format that decides that.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to convert a color to a number is to use the ARGB-Format

```
Color c = Color.Aquamarine;
// Or if you have R-G-B values:  Color c = Color.FromArgb(111,222,333);
int argb = c.ToArgb(); // --> -8388652
string s = argb.ToString(); // --> "-8388652"

// Backwards
argb = Int32.Parse(s);
c = Color.FromArgb(argb);

int R = c.R;
int G = c.G;
int B = c.B;
```

---

UPDATE:

A simple way to store it as string by maintaining the R-G-B-parts would be

```
string s1 = "RGB;123;255;77";
string s2 = "RBG;123;77;255";

string[] parts = s1.Split(';');

int r, g, b;
switch (parts[0]) {
    case "RGB":
        r = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
        g = Int32.Parse(parts[2]);
        b = Int32.Parse(parts[3]);
        break;
    case "RBG":
        r = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
        b = Int32.Parse(parts[2]);
        g = Int32.Parse(parts[3]);
        break;
    default:
        r = 0;
        b = 0;
        g = 0;
        break;
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to convert a number to a color or vice-versa.

Comment: But from the conversation going on above, it looks like you are looking for an appropriate format to store a color as text. Why should this Argb-number format not be an option?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the order, you can get values by using the [string indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx).

Example blatantly stolen from MSDN:

```
string str1 = "Test";
for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= str1.Length - 1; ctr++ )
   Console.Write("{0} ", str1[ctr]);

// The example displays the following output: 
//      T e s t
```

You might also want to look into `System.Drawing.Color`. If it's really colors you are parsing you don't even need to define your own structure.

Comment: I believe by "Know the order" he means that there is some identifier which can identify the order, but it is now known during compilation so that this will not work.  he needs to be able to switch which extraction method is used based on the order identifier.  This would work if there was only one format.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there's some other service that could give you an order and an RGB string?

In that case, let's try to **store types faithfully** and **convert data upon arrival**.

```
public class Color{

public int R{
    get;
    set; 
    }


public int G{
    get;
    set; 
    }

public int B{
    get;
    set; 
    }

public Color(string mixedRGB, string order){
    R = Int32.Parse(mixedRGB.Substring(order.IndexOf('R'),3));
    G = Int32.Parse(mixedRGB.Substring(order.IndexOf('G'),3));
    B= Int32.Parse(mixedRGB.Substring(order.IndexOf('B'),3));
}
```

This will save you space if you have memory constraints and save you sanity from preventing nonsensical values assigned to your objects. (What color does the RGB string "DF)_3nAv1" make?)

You'll know what values correspond to R, G, and B because you store them seperately. IF you need to combine them frequently, you could make a function in this class to combine them.